# ZAP baseline scan doesn't generate report

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, owasp, zap

I'm running the example scan from the [docs page](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/):

```
docker run --rm -v /home/zap:/zap/wrk/:rw -t ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable zap-full-scan.py -t https://www.example.com -r testreport.html
```

The scan seems to finish normally, at leas according to logs (last few lines follow):

> 99208 [ZAP-Scanner-0] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin https://www.example.com | SlackerCookieScanRule in 0.004s with 0 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.

> 99209 [ZAP-Scanner-0] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host https://www.example.com in 46.027s with 6 alert(s) raised.

> 99209 [Thread-26] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Scanner - scanner completed in 46.051s

However, there is nothing in my local /home/zap. I don't know what is wrong. Maybe because I'm using WSL?

EDIT:

As this might be a permission problem, I built a new docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable

# Create the directory
RUN mkdir -p /zap/wrk

# Change ownership of the directory
RUN chown -R zap:zap /zap/wrk

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /zap/wrk
```

Now when I try to run

```
docker run --rm -v /home/zap:/zap/wrk/:rw -t cloud_zap zap-full-scan.py -t https://www.example.com -r testreport.html
```

I get

> 2023-12-02 13:06:19,201 Failed to start ZAP :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a file permissions problem.

Try

> docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable
> touch /zap/wrk/test.txt

Does that create the test.txt file in your CWD?

FYI taken from https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/diagnosing-problems/#cannot-access-created-files

Comment: `touch: cannot touch '/zap/wrk/test.txt': Permission denied`

Comment: So its a file permissions problem :)
Creating the /zap/wrk directory will not help - thats the directory you will be mapping to so it should not exist.

Instead create the testreport.html file in your CWD and `chmod a+w testreport.html` then try again with the standard ZAP image.